# Write file data directly to zip file in C

Tags: c, zip

Currently my program creates a very large and complex directory layout for multiple different files also created by my program. It takes a long time to do so, especially if the files being written are big.

Would it be possible instead of writing necessary data to files in the proper directory to actually write the data to an uncompressed zip file using the same directory layout as in the filesystem with the same names for directories and files but not actually creating those files ever in the filesystem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a library such as [libzip](http://www.nih.at/libzip/) to create and access zip files from a C program.

However, it is unlikely to be much faster, unless your disks are very slow and your CPU is very fast. Random access to the file contents will be quite a bit harder and slower, too, if you need anything else than sequential reading of files from beginning to end.

Comment: I'll try it out and see if I like it. You're right it might not be much faster but I will check anyways. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can  use the [LZO](http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo) it's a real-time data compression library.

Comment: Does it support this kind of functionality? With what I want the files don't already exist in the file system, I just want to put the data for them directly into a zip archive with file names, directory names, etc.

Comment: I'll try it out and see if I like it. Thanks

Comment: Went with libzip in the chosen answer. Thanks for your answer though